# Add column to R summary

Tags: r, statistics

I have an R summary of a vector:

```
summary(vector)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.000   1.000   2.000   6.699   6.000 559.000
```

and I would like to add a column with the standard deviation:

```
SomethingNew(vector)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.   Std.Dev.
1.000   1.000   2.000   6.699   6.000 559.000  17.02
```

The formula for the last column is

```
round(sd(vector),2)
```

but I have no clue as to how to add it to the summary data frame in the same display.  Any help appreciated, cheers.

Comment: I'd recommend using `signif` instead of `round` when rounding here, you're commonly more interested in getting n significant figures than rounding to a specified number of decimal places.

Comment: `summary` uses `signif` with a digits argument of `max(3, getOption("digits")-3)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
vec <- 1:10 # an example vector
summ <- summary(vec) # create the summary

summ["Std.Dev."] <- round(sd(vec),2) # add the new value
```

The result:

```
Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. Std.Dev. 
1.00     3.25     5.50     5.50     7.75    10.00     3.03
```

Answer (score 4):

Try writing a new function to do so.  I have written a short overview of how to write simple functions ([link](http://www.howtor.net/introduction/making-simple-functions)) you can use as a resource.

Essentially, you want the following:

```
mySummary <- function(vector, na.rm = FALSE, round = 2){
  results <- c(summary(vector), 'Std. Dev' = round(sd(vector, na.rm), 2))
  return(results)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
> set.seed(1)
> vector <- rnorm(100, 20, 5)
> c(summary(vector), sd=sd(vector))
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.        sd 
 8.927000 17.530000 20.570000 20.540000 23.460000 32.010000  4.490997
```

rounding:

```
> round(c(summary(vector), sd=sd(vector)), 2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.      sd 
   8.93   17.53   20.57   20.54   23.46   32.01    4.49
```